# I get an error that getInstance(); cannot find the symbol

Tags: java

I get an error. Is `getInstance()` need to imported??

```java
public class GarbageCollector
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getInstance();
        String s ;
        System.out.println(runtime.totalMemory()); // total memory required
        System.out.println(runtime.freeMemory()); // memory freed
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
            s = new String("");
        System.out.println(runtime.freeMemory()); // memory after object"s" 
                                                    //creation                               
        runtime.gc();

        System.out.println(runtime.freeMemory()); // memory after method call
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by having a look at the [JavaDocs for `Runtime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html), you will find that there is no `getInstance` method.  The only `static` method is [`Runtime.getRuntime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#getRuntime())

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime` class has no `getInstance()` method.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getInstance();
```

should be

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
```